# Private data from API::ISteamUser::GetPlayerSummaries

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

I try to pull my private steam data via provided REST API, but whatever I try, it won't show my private info. Here is what I do:

1) grab api key from https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey

2) find my steam id from https://steamid.io (steamID64)

3) access this url: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=&steamids=

It always shows only public info.

Could anyone, please, try the same with his/her account to see if they can get private info?

basically I need to get the "gameid" and "gameextrainfo" when the user is in-game etc.

according to the API:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. You can parse the HTML though, but it's not really... optimal.

Comment: what do you mean its not possible? the steam API offers it.  https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29 under "gameid" and "gameextrainfo"

Comment: "Some data associated with a Steam account may be hidden if the user has their profile visibility set to "Friends Only" or "Private". In that case, only public data will be returned."

Comment: So what I offered was parsing your profile page with your Steam Cookie added to the headers. Though... it makes you load a whole HTML page just to get things you could have gotten from the Web API (but you can't because of your profile privacy)